# backspace and delete issues with the getch() function in DOS

Tags: c, dos, turbo-c

I am using the Turbo C compiler on a Windows platform, Intel x86 architecture.

In my program I am scanning user input from the keyboard. It is a login password program that takes in username and password as user inputs.

For the username I am using getchar(), where while entering the username if the user presses the backspace key, on the keyboard, the previous character gets deleted, on it's own, I mean I don't need to write any explicit code to do this.

But for the password I am using getch() and corresponding to every keystroke I am displaying a * on the screen. In this case if user presses the backspace key on the keyboard, it does not delete the previous character, but rather takes it as another key stroke and displays a * corresponding to it on the screen.

I tried out bioskey from bios.h, tried using \b to work around, none worked.

Any suggestions or workarounds....????

Comment: Turbo C and DOS functions in 2011? Really?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Keep track of the characters for yourself. If your program is receiving the backspace so that it displays a *, then check for that character and back up one space. After backing up one space, print a space to erase the *, then back up again.

Comment: thank you mr Zan. First it i am trying to shift over to gcc and linux but it'll take some time. And second, i did try out what you suggested, but backing up one space just moves the cursor back one space on the screen. It does not really delete the previously printed * from the screen. Any ideas how to implement that...???

Comment: thanx a lot mr. Zan...how stupid of me, i couldn't figure it out...:D ...thanx , it works perfectly as i wanted it to.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to get the passowrd:

```
int i;
char c,*buf;
printf("Password: ");
for(i=0;(c=getch())!='\r';)
{
     //checking wheter the entered character is backspace  NOTE: ASCII value for '\b' is 8
    if(c!=8)
    {
        buf[i]=c;
        printf("*");
        i++;
    }
    else
    {
        i--;
        if(i<0)
            i++;
        else
            printf("\b \b");//implementing the effect of backspace
    }
}
buf[i]='\0';//terminating the password string 
printf("%s",buf);//to check the input password is stored correctly or not, i displayed them
getch();
```

I hope that this will help you.. :-D:-D..